# Frequency Measurement using FPGA and VHDL

Tags: fpga, vhdl, frequency-measurement

I am not very experienced at VHDL coding. I want to measure the frequency of my input signal. It varies between 1 Hz to 150 kHz. And my clock frequency is 250 MHz. I wrote some code but it is not working properly. Could someone help me please? How can i handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an answerable EE question to ask?

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve, in general. The usual approach is to use something like the MUSIC algorithm. We need more information: what is your input signal; your window size; SNR; amplitude range; analog or digital; if analog, how is it sampled, i.e. ADC ENOB.

Comment: What are the specifications on the frequency measurement? How accurate? How fast?  Is it a digitised signal, or a logic-levels clock? If digitised, is the input waveform a single frequency, does it have constant amplitude? There are as many ways to go about 'measuring frequency', depending on what you are trying to measure. Post your code, it might give us a clue as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have someone who did that, in this case it uses 2 asynchronous gated counters, one from the reference, one from the signal, they are gated by a third counter fed form the ref, the precision of the measurement can be set by adjusting the gate comparator threshold.
all implemented with an fpga and a micro controller (plus some auxiliary circuitry which you may or not use)

https://andybrown.me.uk/2016/02/21/nanocounter/